# Spark geo tiles join

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've got a problem with the performance of my spark task.

I've got two tables:

- geo fishnet with cells size 200x200 meters. Size about 2 millions rows. Schema:

  `cell_id minlat minlon maxlat maxlon`
- geo objects. Size about 200 thousands rows. Schema:

  `objid lat lon`

What i want is to join these tables and find the cell for each object. Desired schema:

```
objid lat lon cell_id
```

The first naive solution is:

```
  cellDF.join(objDF, callUDF("isContain", col("minlat"),..col("lat"), col("lon")));
```

where UDF just check `minlat <= lat <= maxlat && minlon <= lon <= maxlon`

But this solutions work very slow. Several hours on cluster with 20+ nodes.

The second thing I've tried - using [esri-geometry-api](https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java). I created `Polygon` for each cell and `Point` for each object and check `polygon.contains(point)`.
But this solution works slower than the first.

Maybe there are "the best practices" for such kind of joins in spark? I found some information about QuadTree, but didn't find any clear documentation and examples for this algorithm in spark.

P.S. Spark version is 2.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose that you have two csv files (if it isn't true you need only to change the input)

```
// Create a spark session
SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().appName("name here").getOrCreate();

// Create datasets for both input
Dataset<Fishnet> fishnet = session.read().format("csv").option("header", true).option("inferSchema", true).load("fishnet.csv").as(Encoders.bean(Fishnet.class));
Dataset<GeoObject> geoObject = session.read().format("csv").option("header", true).option("inferSchema", true).load("geoObject.csv").as(Encoders.bean(GeoObject.class));

// Create temp view on datasets
fishnet.createOrReplaceTempView("fishnet");
geoObject.createOrReplaceTempView("geoObject");

// Now create a query to retrieve the result [objid lat lon cell_id]
Dataset<Row> result = session.sql("select objid, lat, lon, cell_id from fishnet, geoObject where lat >= minlat and lat <= maxlat and lon >= minlon and lon <= maxlon");
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea to try. My inputs are parquet tables in Hive, so I think I can just use `spark.sql(...)` for this tables.